# How to create a cyclical pause effect with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm still trying to find the video pause effect. It's like the network can't load that video. Example: My video reaches 5 seconds and stops (time still counts) after 2 seconds the video resumes and repeats till the end. The above method only helps for short videos. I want it to repeat cyclically to the end of the video

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex \ "[0:v]split=4[v0][v1][v2][v3];
[v0]trim=start_frame=0:end_frame=1,loop=90:1:0,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[0v];
[v1]trim=start_frame=1:end_frame=301,loop=90:1:299,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[1v];
[v2]trim=start_frame=301:end_frame=601,loop=90:1:299,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[2v];
[v3]trim=start_frame=601:end_frame=900,loop=90:1:298,setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB[3v];
aevalsrc=0:d=3[0a];
[0:a]asplit=3[a1][a2][a3];
[a1]atrim=0:10,asetpts=N/SR/TB[1a];
[a2]atrim=10:20,asetpts=N/SR/TB[2a];
[a3]atrim=20:30,asetpts=N/SR/TB[3a];
[0v][0a][1v][1a][2v][2a][3v][3a]concat=n=4:v=1:a=1[v][a]"
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" outva.mp4
```

Comment: What stops you from doing exactly that for a long video?

Comment: I can't endlessly repeat it if the videos are too long. I am looking for a solution to restrict the command line,

Comment: If you run into problems with a (4K long) command line, you can create parts, where each fits into a 4K command line, then splice them. Use a shell script to create your command line(s)